# Jquery doesnt work when transpilled to es5

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, browserify

Typescript code:

```
import * as $ from "jquery";
import {Canvas} from "./canvas";

$(() => {
    let canvas = new Canvas(600, 600);
    canvas.init();
});
```

i use browserify and it compiles typescript import into

```
var _jquery = require("jquery");
var $ = _interopRequireWildcard(_jquery);

$(function () {
    var canvas = new _canvas.Canvas(600, 600);
    canvas.init();
});
```

and this error is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
```

everything is ok when i replace $ with _jQuery in console, how can i remove that _interopRequireWildcard() call??

Comment: You need to use jquery as an Ambient, or a module. Currently I guess you have just downloaded jquery from the website and saved it as jquery.js?

Comment: You need to use npm to install jquery on your app, and then your code above should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing jQuery's default export, like this:

```
import $ from "jquery";
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: This is correct. Specifically, a namespace cannot be `[[Call]]ed` or `[[Construct]]ed` and the implementation of `interopRequireWildcard` is likely ensuring the spec is adhered to.

Comment: I have tried it before but there was an error TS1192 Module ''jquery'' has no default export. "allowSyntheticDefaultImports" : true fixed this problem